# is the AMD Radeon HD 5700 card supported?

Tags: gpu, hardware

I have a graphic card AMD Radeon HD 5700.

Is this card is supported in Blender 2.81?

I cant find the answer.

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#amd

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately your graphics card doesn't fulfill the [minimum requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/) for Blender 2.8x. [GCN first generation or later](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_graphics_processing_units#API_Overview) is required for AMD GPUs. Your graphics card has the older Terascale architecture.